# Filter containing specific record(tag) and return records Ember-data

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I have a model called question and subject:

```
App.Question = DS.Model.extend({
  title: DS.attr('string'),
  description: DS.attr('string'),
  answers: DS.hasMany('answer',{async:true }),
  subjects: DS.hasMany('subject',{async:true })
});

App.Subject = DS.Model.extend({
  description: DS.attr('string'),
  question: DS.belongsTo('question')
});
```

I want to return all the questions that have a tagged with specific subject for example

```
findAll questions where subjects.contain(aSubject)
```

Do i have to implement a filter on the embedded SubjectsArray or is there a slick way to do this with Ember-data?

thanks

Comment: My take on this is that Ember Data will only help you submit a request to your server, but it can't know upfront how you want to process your search criteria. So, when you call `this.store.find('question', { subject: 'stackOverflow' }`, Ember Data will make a GET request with that JSON object (question/stackoverflow) serialized as query params. For local searches only, there may be some other options I'm now aware of.

Comment: yes, you are right, as hooking up to server this can be easily query by serializing the params request. As for local options, i suspect we could filter the array of (inner) subjects find out question id since we are having DS.belongsTo relationship, then return those questions respectively. You think it would be an appropriate approach.

Comment: I think your filter sounds like a good idea.  You could probably implement this as a computed property in either your controller (if it's page-specific) or your `DS.Model` (if it's common to the model). You can just depend on the `content` property and call `this.get('content')` within your computed property and then do some kind of transform on it.